# What's wrong with my conky.conf?

Tags: desktop, conky

I have been using this configuration for conky for some time on debian but, for some reason, it does not work on Alpine Linux.
When i launch conky from the terminal I get:

```
    alpine:~$ conky &
    [1] 4288
    alpine:~$ conky: desktop window (110) is root window
    conky: window type - desktop
    conky: drawing to created window (0x1200002)
    conky: drawing to double buffer
    conky: one or more $endif's are missing
    conky: forked to background, pid is 4289
```

this is the .conkyrc file

```
conky.config = {
alignment = 'top_right',
background = true,
color2 = 'b4ca9e',
cpu_avg_samples = 2,
default_color = '9ab87c',
    draw_shades = false,
double_buffer = true,
font = 'Cantarell:size=9',
gap_x = 10,
gap_y = 50,
minimum_width = 200,
no_buffers = true,
own_window = true,
own_window_type = 'desktop',
own_window_transparent = true,
own_window_argb_visual = true,
own_window_argb_value = 255, 
own_window_hints = 'undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',
update_interval = 1.0,
use_xft = true,
}
conky.text = [[
${voffset 8}$color2${font Cantarell:size=16}${time %a}$font${voffset -8}$alignr${color   
db6823}${font Cantarell:size=38}${time %e}$font
$color2${voffset -30}$color2${font Cantarell:size=18}${time %b}$font${voffset -3} 
$color2${font Cantarell:size=20}${time %Y}$font
#
${voffset 10}${color2} Alpine=

#
${voffset 10}${if_up wlp9s0}$color2 wlp9s0 $alignr ${addr wlp9s0}
$color2 Up $alignr$color2${upspeed wlan0} ${upspeedgraph wlp9s0 6,70}
$color2 Total $alignr$color2 ${totalup wlp9s0}
$color2 Down $alignr$color2 ${downspeed wlan0} ${downspeedgraph wlp9s0 6,70}
$color2 Total $alignr$color2 $color2${totaldown wlp9s0}
$color2 SSID $alignr$color2 ${wireless_essid wlp9s0}
$color2 Signal $alignr$color2 ${wireless_link_qual wlp9s0}% ${wireless_link_bar wlp9s0}  
$color2 Bitrate $alignr$color2 ${wireless_bitrate wlp9s0}
#
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${color2}CPU Average$alignr$cpu%
${voffset 10}$color2  ${cpugraph CPU0 $color2 $color2}
${voffset 10}${goto 40}$color2}CPU 1$alignr${cpu cpu1}%
${voffset 10}${goto 40}$color2}CPU 2$alignr${cpu cpu2}%
${voffset 10}${goto 40}$color2}CPU 3$alignr${cpu cpu3}%
${voffset 10}${goto 40}$color2}CPU 4$alignr${cpu cpu4}%
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${color2}CPU Temp$alignr$acpitemp°C
${voffset 5}${goto 40}$font$color2${top name 1}$alignr$color2${top cpu 1}%
${goto 40}$color2${top name 2}$alignr$color2${top cpu 2}%
${goto 40}$color2${top name 3}$alignr$color2${top cpu 3}%
${goto 40}$color2${top name 4}$alignr$color2${top cpu 4}%
#
${voffset 10}${goto 40}${color2}RAM$alignr$mem
${goto 40}${voffset 5}$color2${top_mem name 1}$alignr$color2${top_mem mem_res 1}
${goto 40}$color2${top_mem name 2}$alignr$color2${top_mem mem_res 2}
${goto 40}$color2${top_mem name 3}$alignr$color2${top_mem mem_res 3}
${goto 40}$color2${top_mem name 4}$alignr$color2${top_mem mem_res 4}
#
${voffset 10}$alignr${color2}hd ${fs_size /} - ${fs_used /}
${alignr}${color2}${font Cantarell:size=9}mem $memmax - $mem
${alignr}${color2}${font Cantarell:size=9}swap $swapmax - $swap
#
${alignr}${color2}${font Cantarell:size=9}uptime ${color2}${uptime_short}
${alignr}${color2}${font Cantarell:size=9}${alignr}kernel ${color2}${kernel}
${alignr}${color2}${font Cantarell:size=9}${alignr}architecture ${color2}${machine}
${alignr}${color2}${font Cantarell:size=9}${alignr}file system ${color2}${fs_type}
]]
```

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the `${if_...}` constructs need a matching terminating `$endif`, which your config does not have. Presumably, an older version of conky did not check for this error.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that.